# Dynamic scoping in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

Is it possible to do something like this in ruby on rails?

```
def method(scope: 'all') # so that it would use Model.all by default
  Model.scope
end

method(scope: 'last(10)') # to get it to call Model.last(10)
```

Update: For clarification, this is not particularly related to the [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) class method in Rails. I probably should have avoided using the term "scope" when originally asking, to avoid confusion. Feel free to think about it as `model_method` instead. Will leave the question as originally stated though, to preserve history as one of the answers addressed it as such.

Comment: You already have `Model.all` and `Model.last(10)` in rails

Comment: What is your question exactly it's quite confusing

Comment: I want it to dynamically call either `Model.all` or `Model.last(10)` or `Model.some_other_method`, based on what I set `scope` to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can define respective scopes in Model itself, to handle with and without arguments..

```
scope :scoping, ->(method = 'all') { send(method) }
scope :scoping_with_arg, ->(method = 'limit', arg = 1) { send(method, arg) }
```

Then,

```
Model.scoping('first')
Model.scoping_with_arg('last', 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I want to determine the actual scope to call dynamically during runtime.

Comment: Please don't tell me you're sending the scope from a browser.

Comment: @Magne please explain *dynamically during runtime*, I think it is pretty *dynamic* in itself

Comment: @radubogdan haha, no, that would be very foolish :) on the other hand... it would take sql injection style attacks to a whole new level ~_~

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I want it to dynamically call either `Model.all` or `Model.last(10)` or `Model.some_other_method`, based on what the contents of the variable `scope` is when the program is run.

Comment: can you guarantee all `scopes` would be valid `scopes`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon just as far as I'm the one hardcoding them somewhere else in the program.

Comment: @Magne I'm not a fan of `#send` and using relation merging or `#instance_exec` in my projects for dynamic calls, but it seems @Md.FarhanMemon provides code which exactly did what you asked. If he didn't, may be your question should be clarified.

Comment: @Magne maybe a list of `scopes` you are going to hardcode will help analyse pattern and write a method for it, else, there are endless cases to handel

Answer (score 0):

I found out how, by using ruby's `#send` and `keyword arguments`, and using an array to support model scopes with more than just one argument:

```
def method(scope: 'all', scope_args: []) # so that the method would call Model.all by default
  Model.send(scope, *scope_args)
end

method(scope: 'last', scope_args: [10]) # to get it to call Model.last(10)
method(scope: 'where', scope_args: [attribute: 'something']) # to get the method to call Model.where(attribute: 'something')
```

Comment: Exactly, you can't have just a string to scope it all, need to pass arguments seperately..

Comment: Well, you could, but then you'd have to parse the string with regex to extract the parameters from the parenthesis. It didn't seem worth it just to avoid the second parameter. Thanks for the hint on providing a second parameter to `#send`, it was helpful!

Comment: I tried that already, but it didn't cover all cases/chainable scopes that's the reason I asked you for a list.

Comment: FFR: Althogh this implementation worked, I ended up dropped it since it would incur too much knowledge debt. Refactored the code into separate methods in separate places in the app instead. DRY'ing up the code isn't always good, if it comes at the expense of readability and intuition.